# MKS Integrity: open item from command line

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

I would like to open a item in MKS from the command line using the item number:

```
command 123456
```

and get directly to the gui item view. I've been googling around for API examples, but haven't found anything helpful yet. In the extension I'll use it to make a shortcut from my text editor.

Hope this is possible, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`im viewissue` is the cli command for "View Item".
In your case, the command should be like this:

```
im viewissue --hostname=%mks_host% --port=%mks_im_port% --user=%mks_user% --gui %item_id%
```

where `%mks_host%`, `%mks_im_port%`, `%mks_user%` and `%item_id%` should be replaced with the proper values.

`im viewissue` command usage

```
Usage: im viewissue options... item id...; options are:
    --asOf=[<date>|label:<label>]  View the item(s) as of a historical date or label
    --height=value  The height in pixels of the windows
    --[no]showAnnotations  Display annotations
    --[no]showAttachmentDetails  Display all attachment attributes
    --[no]showAttachments  Display attachments
    --[no]showBranches  Display branches
    --[no]showChangePackages  Display change packages
    --[no]showDecorators  Display "!" for ambiguous field values
    --[no]showHistory  Display history
    --[no]showHistoryAscending  Display history in chronological order
    --[no]showHistoryWithComputedField  Display history with computed fields
    --[no]showHistoryWithIndirectEdits  Display history with indirect edits (CLI/API only)
    --[no]showLabels  Display labels
    --[no]showLock  Display lock information
    --[no]showRelationships  Display relationships
    --[no]showRichContent  Display rich text field data as rich content
    --[no]showSourceLinkDetails  Display all source link and source trace attributes
    --[no]showSourceTraceDetails  Display all source link and source trace attributes
    --[no]showTestResults  Display test results
    --[no]showTimeEntries  Display time entries
    --[no]showWorkflow  Display workflow
    --[no]showXHTML  Display rich text field data as XHTML
    --[no]substituteParams  Substitute parameters
    --width=value  The width in pixels of the windows
    -x value  The x location in pixels of the window
    -y value  The y location in pixels of the window
    -?  Shows the usage for a command
    --[no]batch  Control batch mode (no user interaction in batch mode)
    --cwd=value  Act as if command executed in specified directory
    -F value  Read the selection from a specified file
    --forceConfirm=[yes|no]  Specify an answer to all confirmation questions
    -g  User interaction should happen via the GUI
    --gui  User interaction should happen via the GUI
    --hostname=value  Hostname of server
    -N  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
    --no  Responds to all confirmations with "no"
    --password=value  Credentials (e.g., password) to login with
    --port=value  TCP/IP port number of server
    --quiet  Control status display
    --selectionFile=value  Read the selection from a specified file
    --settingsUI=[gui|default]  Control UI for command options
    --status=[none|gui|default]  Control status display
    --usage  Shows the usage for a command
    --user=value  Username to login to server with
    -Y  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
    --yes  Responds to all confirmations with "yes"
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there does not seem to be a standard API command to bring you to an item in the Web GUI from the CLI, there is a standard URL you can construct to view any given item directly from a web browser.

The URL to access an item directly by it's item ID via a web browser will be:

> **%host_server%:%port%/im/viewissue?selection=%item_id%**

where:

- %host_server% is the full URL address of the server hosting the Integrity application.
- %port% is the port number of the Integrity application on the host server.
- %item_id% is the integer item ID to view.

Example: If my Integrity application is available on the server https://myhostserver.com at port 1234 and the Item ID I want to view is 123456, then the URL to construct is:

> https://myhostserver.com:1234/im/viewissue?selection=123456

This link can then be dynamically created to access any existing Integrity item ID. Users will still be required to authenticate within Integrity before the item can be viewed.